# Page Numbers not Behaving as expected in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'm putting page numbers in the footer of my document and I find that it will count up to nine and reset back to 1 where the the next 10 pages are all page 1 before it then goes and makes the next 10 pages page 2 and so on. They're all in the same section so the footers are linked with each other where trying to fix one changes it for the entire section, it's marked to start counting at 1 and not to show chapters. I saw somewhere online someone recommended saving as XML and opening that and resaving as Docx, but that did not help. As a last-ditch effort I even tried copying the entire document to Notepad to remove all formatting, then pasting back into Word and had no luck there either. Same thing. I'm going bonkers! Why won't the page numbering just work?? This is happening in both Word 2010 and 2013.

Comment: "even tried copying the entire document to Notepad to remove all formatting" - so do you have also this strange behavior in all new documents (e.g. entering 10 page breaks), or does it fine and gets corrupted only when you paste the specific content? is it possible to upload that file (of course without any confidential information) and share it with us?

Comment: Did you try on a different PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, and wow is it dumb. The default formatting of the page number that I selected is only wide enough to show one digit. Once I widened it I could clearly see that the 1 was 10 and that it was in the 10s for 10 digits until it became 20 when I started seeing only 2!